# Prove that two finite sets have the same cardinality if and only if there exists a bijection between them

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The textbook "Discrete Mathematics with Applications" by Thomas Koshy states a theorem (3.5):

For function $f: X \rightarrow  Y$, where

- $X$ is the finite domain and
- $Y$ is the finite co-domain

> Two finite sets have the same cardinality *if and only if* there exists
> a bijection between them.

I can prove that if $f$ is a bijective function then $|X| = |Y|$.
However, I am struggling to understand Koshy's proof for the biconditional part.
For example, in the case below where $|X| = |Y|$, the sets have the same cardinality but are not bijective:

- $X = \{-2,-1,1,2\}$
- $Y = \{0, 1, 2, 4\}$
- $f(x) = x^2$

Any ideas if Koshy's proof is wrong, or if not, how one would go about proving this?

edit: adding Koshy's proof below

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two finite sets with $|X| = m$ and $|Y| = n$.
Let $X = \{x_1, . . . , x_m\}$.
Let $f : X → Y$ be bijective.
Since $f$ is injective, $f(x_1), . . . , f (x_m)$
are $m$ distinct elements in $Y$. Consequently, $m \leq n$. Since $f$ is surjective, every element $y$ in $Y$ has at least one input in $X$, so $n \leq m$. Thus $|X| = |Y|$.

Conversely, suppose $m = n$ and $Y = \{y_1, . . . , y_m\}$. Define a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ by $f(x_i) = y_i$ for every $i$. We will now show that f is injective. Let $x_j$ and $x_k$ be two elements in $X$ such that $f (x_j) = f (x_k)$. Then, by definition,
$y_j = y_k$; so, $j = k$ and hence $x_j = x_k$. Therefore, $f$ is injective and hence, by Theorem 3.4, $f$ is bijective.

Theorem 3.4: Let $X$ and $Y$ be any two finite sets with $|X| = |Y| = n$. A function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is injective if and only if $f$ is surjective.

Comment: This is hard to follow. The fact that two sets admit a bijection between them, certainly does not imply that *every* function between them is a bijection.

Comment: What the theorem is saying is not "for every function $f : X \to Y$, if $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinal then $f$ is bijective" but rather "for every pair of sets $(X,Y)$, if $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinal then there exists a function $f : X \to Y$ which is bijective". That is, to show it to be wrong (spoiler: it's *not* wrong) you would have to show that all functions between your two sets are not bijective.

Comment: I strongly doubt that Koshi's theorem includes "For function $f: X \rightarrow  Y$, where 
- $X$ is the finite domain and 
- $Y$ is the finite co-domain". The statement "Two finite sets have the same cardinality *if and only if* there exists
a bijection between them" involves no function $f.$

Comment: You need to provide a precise definition of cardinality. The general definition of cardinality makes your theorem follow almost by definition.

Comment: @MohanGupta The f you chose is not the same type as Koshy's f. If you choose an f of the same type as Koshy's you find a bijection.

Comment: "I can prove that if $f$ is a bijective function then $|X| = |Y|$.
However, I am struggling to understand Koshy's proof for the biconditional part. "     Well, which step don't you understand in (the second part of) this proof?

Comment: @MohanGupta "There exists" doesn't mean that all functions are bijective. The second half of Koshy's proof claims that it has found at least one bijection, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Q is not "*the* function ..." (which one?)  but "*some* function...". Mind the phrase "there exists" in the statement. In the second part of his proof he takes $X,Y$ of same cardinality and constructs a bijection between them.

Comment: Precisely! And not iff *your* function between them is bijective.  "there exists a bijection" means "there exists at least a bijection" or equivalently "there exists some bijection"

Comment: His answer is cleaner but I think you understood, despite some faulty wordings: 1) Your function disproves nothing. 2) The cardinalities being the same or not is independent of any function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need all functions to be bijective, you just need for there to be at least 1.

$X, Y$ finite means we can write
$$X = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m\} \qquad\text{and}\qquad Y = \{y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n\}$$
for some $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_i$ are distinct for all $i$ and similarly for $y_i$. $|X| = |Y|$ means that $m=n$.

Define the natural bijection $f:X\to Y$ with $f(x_i) = y_i$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots, n$. It's easy to check this is injective, and it clearly has an inverse with a similar looking expression.

P.S. Imagine $f:\{0,1\}\to\{0,1\}$ with $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. This is not a bijection but the sets are clearly the same and so there's a bijection between them.

Comment: The sets are not bijective. "Bijective" is a property about functions, not about sets.

Comment: @jjagmath That's fair I guess I made that term up (I was using it in the same sense that you might say two spaces are isomorphic if there's an isomorphism between them).

Comment: @MohanGupta No worries, have a good day :)